# can i detect whether a web user has a software keyboard using javascript?

Tags: javascript, smartphone

I'd like to have the search field on my website automatically gain focus when the user loads the page, but i don't like how that pops up the keyboard for users on smartphones/tablets.  Is there any javascript property I can use to detect whether or not the user has physical keyboard connected?

Comment: I'm not sure this will work the way you intend. If you disable the keyboard, they won't be able to type in the box without tapping outside the search box and then re-tapping inside it. Why not just code a little CSS or javascript that says if the browser is a mobile browser, then don't load with focus on the search bar.

Comment: i am curious what google does because they also set focus to the search field on load.

Comment: @akonsu Google's search "field" isn't actually a text box, it's a `<div>` plus some Javascript. So it doesn't pop the keyboard detection.

Comment: Brian: i don't want to disable the keyboard.  if the user has a soft keyboard, i just don't want to focus the search field on page load.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about that...but if you check [this](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/11/detecting-mobile-devices-with-javascript/) link out, it'll show you how to detect whether a user is on a mobile platform or not. you could make your decision based on that?

Comment: That was kind of what i was hoping to avoid, but it looks like it might end up being the best way.